# javascript variables conflict

Tags: javascript, unobtrusive-javascript

I was included 2 javascript files in my app with script tag.

I was declared same variable in both script.

Now my question is, If I run the app will the variable same for two scripts or different for each script.

script 1(external file included).

```
var myvariable=10;
function(){
...
}
```

script 2 (external file)

```
var myvariable=20;
function(){
...
}
```

Is both myvariables are same for app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That depends on the scope.

If both variables are global (ie: window.var) then the last variable will over-write the first variable with the same name.

Look into closures to fix this (should you be using conflicting global variables).

Good Luck !!

**TO YOUR UPDATED QUESTION:**
myvariable is in global scope, after script 2 executes myvariable will be 20.

Comment: Damn I was just writing this and started with exactly the same sentence :) You won. +1 :)

Comment: @Marc: lol, the [fastest gun problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem?lq=1) hihi. Well, great minds... :) Thx for the upvote!

Answer (score 0):

If you declare a variable globally and then you again declare a variable with same name then it overrides the variable.